# Filter out div child element in xpath

Tags: xpath

I have the following xpath expression :

```
//div[@class='a-section a-spacing-none a-spacing-top-small']
```

This selection contains `<div class= "a-row a-spacing-micro">` i want to do a not contains on this class `a-row a-spacing-micro`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this on your html and see if it works:

```
//div[not(@class='a-section a-spacing-none a-spacing-top-small')]
```